# How can I extract the certain content from the URL?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am a student and is working on an assignment. I am asked to use BeautifulSoup library to analyze the page (https://www.edb.gov.hk/en/about-edb/press/press-releases/index.html) and extract the table or list; then to store the data in a python list or dict or pandas dataframe. (This is the requirement).

I successfully extracted the link and the title name using "for loop" with the tag "a" and "a href". However, I don't know how to extract the "date" from the web.

Can someone give me some advice by using "div:nth-of-type" or other methods please?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article [ask] about how to asking questions also read this article [mre] about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement. Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

To get Date, Title and Link to a dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.edb.gov.hk/en/about-edb/press/press-releases/index.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

all_data = []
for row in soup.select(".circulars_result_row:has(.table_text_mobile)"):
    data = [d.get_text(strip=True) for d in row.select(".table_text_mobile")]
    all_data.append(data + [row.a["href"]])

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["Date", "Title", "Link"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
           Date                                                                                                                Title                                                                         Link
0   11 Oct 2021  EDB provides latest guidelines on display of national flag and conduct of national flag raising ceremony in schools  https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/general/202110/11/P2021101100304.htm?fontSize=1
1   11 Oct 2021                                                   Hong Kong Scholarship for Excellence Scheme opens for applications  https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/general/202110/11/P2021100800399.htm?fontSize=1
2   11 Oct 2021                                                                              Profiles of kindergartens posted online             https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/general/202110/11/P2021101100297.htm
3   05 Oct 2021                                           "Active Students, Active People" Campaign cum e-Gallery launching ceremony  https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/general/202110/05/P2021100400564.htm?fontSize=1
4   30 Sep 2021                                                                             EDB launches "SENSE" information website  https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/general/202109/30/P2021092900520.htm?fontSize=1
5   23 Sep 2021                                          Launch of School Nominations Direct Admission Scheme for local universities  https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/general/202109/23/P2021092300346.htm?fontSize=1
6   21 Sep 2021                                 Study Subsidy Scheme for Designated Professions/Sectors for 2022/23 cohort announced             https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/general/202109/21/P2021092000818.htm
7   20 Sep 2021                                                  EDB announces arrangements for student grant of 2021/22 school year             https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/general/202109/20/P2021092000578.htm
8   16 Sep 2021                                             Parents reminded to submit application form for admission to Primary One  https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/general/202109/16/P2021091600299.htm?fontSize=1
9   13 Sep 2021                      Junior Secondary History e-Reading Award Scheme fosters students' positive values and attitudes  https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/general/202109/13/P2021091300317.htm?fontSize=1
10  03 Sep 2021                                                                                         SED on Primary One admission  https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/general/202109/03/P2021090300473.htm?fontSize=1
11  02 Sep 2021                               EDB introduces newly developed Curriculum Framework on Parent Education (Kindergarten)  https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/general/202109/02/P2021090200238.htm?fontSize=1
12  01 Sep 2021                                                                       Appointments to Curriculum Development Council             https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/general/202109/01/P2021090100172.htm
13  01 Sep 2021                                                                                       SED speaks on first school day             https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/general/202109/01/P2021090100352.htm
```